# Why am I getting: Uncaught ReferenceError: Button is not defined (ReactJS and Elemental UI)?

Tags: html, reactjs, uicomponents

I followed the installation for Elemental UI ( http://elemental-ui.com/ ) with ReactJS with the following:

npm install elemental

And successfully installed everything. But once I attempt to use one of the components, say for example:

```
<Button type="primary">Primary</Button>
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Button is not defined
```

Any insight or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you forgot to import the `Button` component.

```
import { Button } from 'elemental'
```

Comment: Thank you! It compiles successfully now, but it comes out to be just a regular default button. What may be the issue?

Comment: Probably missing stylesheets. Their documentation isn't really helpful. However the github repo shows some `.less`-stylesheets, this requires you to depend on the `less`-compiler to compile `less` to `css`. I'd go for some other library actually :-) Google around a bit.